# Should i install testng as eclipse plugin to run the test in Eclipse

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created a class and have some annotation methods like `@BforeTest` and `@Test` methods and also included `testng.jar` in build path, so there are no syntax errors nothing...

In order to run this class, should i be installing testng plugin?

Are there any other ways to run this script?

Comment: Please go through this link http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html. You will find all the answers.

Comment: If you need to run through eclipse then yes u need to install testng plugin else run through command line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to run testNG program using eclipse you need to install testng plugin.

Please install testng plugin as per below steps :

1 - Open Eclipse

2 - Go to Help -> Install new software

3 - Click on Add

4 - set Name : testNG & Location : http://beust.com/eclipse & click to OK

5 - Click on next

6 - Accept terms & click on finish

7 - It will show you warning , click ok

8 - It will ask to restart eclipse , say Yes

Once restart eclipse , then go to your project , do right click on that and you will see option called "TestNG"  , So now you able to create & run TestNG class directly from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to install TestNG framework

Best article for TestNG plugin Installation with only 5-6 steps.

Visit Here: [TestNG Plugin Installation With Screenshots](http://webapps4newbies.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-install-testng-framework-as.html?spref=tw)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must install TestNG.
Rather than me explaining how to install you can refer to the following link
http://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html